# How to set TabIndex to a ComboBox within a ContentControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabindex

I have following code -

```
<ContentControl KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="6"> //Point A
                            <ContentControl.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <ContentControl x:Name="content">
                                        <ContentControl.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Property1}"
                                                  Margin="0, 7" >
                                                    <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                                                        <Binding Path="PropertyText" />
                                                    </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                                                </ComboBox>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </ContentControl.Template>
                                    </ContentControl>

                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Property1}" Value="val1">
                                            <Setter TargetName="content" Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                                        <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Propert2}"
                                                          Margin="0, 7">
                                                            <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                                                                <Binding Path="val2" />
                                                            </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                                                        </ComboBox>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ContentControl.Template>
                        </ContentControl>
```

**Explanation**

See the Point A. The TabIndex is working fine, but if I move this to internal elements like ComboBox, it goes to next TabIndex. Also I have a trigger.

**Requirement**

Whichever Combobox is visible should get TabIndex="6".

The parent control i.e. ContentControl should not get any TabIndex.

Please suggest. Thanx in advance.

Comment: You can forward the tab navigation by KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" and use TabNavigation="Local" on your ComboBox.

Comment: @deafjeff: Thanx, but it is not working.